# Execution definition in JMM

Tags: java, java-memory-model

An execution E is described by a tuple < P, A, po, so, W, V, sw, hb >, comprising:

```
P - a program

A - a set of actions

po - program order, which for each thread t, is a total order over all actions performed by t in A

so - synchronization order, which is a total order over all synchronization actions in A

W - a write-seen function, which for each read r in A, gives W(r), the write action seen by r in E.

V - a value-written function, which for each write w in A, gives V(w), the value written by w in E.

sw - synchronizes-with, a partial order over synchronization actions

hb - happens-before, a partial order over actions
```

What in there is the set of actions? Does that defintion relate to a specifiec thread `t`? Or one covers all threads which program starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tuple `E`, `A` is the set of *all inter-thread actions* committed by an execution of the program `P`.